# "CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, external, prefix

I have been trying insall node js and install browser sync

```
C:\Users\Aly>npm install -g browser-sync
'CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files `(x86)\nodejs\\`
node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Even if i want to know my node js version , the same error appear and then the version shown after that

```
C:\Users\Aly>npm --version
'CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files `(x86)\nodejs\\`
node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
3.10.9
```

Windows 10

Thanks So Much In Advance

Comment: how did you install node?

Comment: why there's \\ before `node.exe`? you must've installed nodejs incorrectly.

Comment: @DanielA.White Like here exactly : http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows
When i finished installing node js there was an error "warning 1909 could not create shortcut node.js command prompt.lnk"

Answer (score 2):

I just spend way to long with this issue.  I'm not sure how it got set, perhaps during an install, but I changed a System Variable:

Name: ComSpec
Value: %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;prefix=C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe

To this:

Name: ComSpec
Value: %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe

And restarted my system and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Good catch blur0224.

I also spent way too long on this issue reinstalling `node` in various ways and investigating `administrator privileges` for the `%appdata%/roaming/npm -folder`.

Your solution worked for me also. The `ComSpec variable` contained old trash (referring to uninstalled programs) which somehow interfered when calling npm.

Side **note 1**: What was REALLY confusing was that calling npm worked for many npm package retrievals, but not all. Error code in the failed cases would for me contain keywords such as `code ELIFECYCLE` and `errno ENOENT`.

Side **note 2**: I also received `warning 1909 could not create shortcut node.js command prompt.lnk` when installing node - perhaps implying that an environmental variable was not properly installed.

Anyone seeing the symptoms from the two previous paragraphs could try the answer from blur0224. I hope this helps people searching for these keywords.

Comment: This seems really a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Either is fine with me, Alejandro. I wish for others who are struggling with this issue to see the additional symptoms I was observing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check using GitBash whether the `npm -v` command executes successfully.

If NPM is working in GitBash, then it is not a path problem (*your path reference is OK*).

Go to *Environment Variables* > *System Variables* and check if `ComSpec: %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe` is correctly configured, or not.

In some cases, if you have a trailing slash, it will not work. (eg: `ComSpec : %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe\`) If so, simple remove the trailing slash.

Otherwise, check where `cmd.exe` is located and use that path as the `ComSpec` value.

Usually, it resides at `c://Windows/System32/cmd.exe`.