# Why any of my npm commands not working ? always gives ERR whine installing npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, config

```
C:\Users\lenovo>node -v
v14.16.0

C:\Users\lenovo>npm -v
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
6.14.11

C:\Users\lenovo>npm config
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm config set <key> <value>
npm ERR! npm config get [<key>]
npm ERR! npm config delete <key>`enter code here`
npm ERR! npm config list [--json]
npm ERR! npm config edit
npm ERR! npm set <key> <value>
npm ERR! npm get [<key>]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! alias: c

C:\Users\lenovo>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278363/

Answer (score 0):

You run `npm config` but this command need options and/or parameters. It was explained after `npm ERR! Usage:`

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config)